# Добраться до содержимого фрейма

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Есть страница, в которую "впихнут" iframe. Нужно добавить script в head фрейма. Интересует, возможно ли это сделать? Желательно кроссбраузерно (ниже IE 9 не интересует).

---

Готовый код не прошу бросать. Не обязательно выполнять именно вставку js в iframe, достаточно будет помочь хоть как-то добраться до его содержимого. Вполне возможно использовать библиотеки типа jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы знаете id этого ифрейма или можете каким-то другим способом заполучить его объект (например `var oIframe = $('myIframe')`, то вам становятся доступны `oIframe.contentWindow.document.body`, `oIframe.contentWindow.document.head` и т.д.

Вернее, тру кросс-броузерно будет:

```
var iFrameDoc = oIframe.contentDocument || oIframe.contentWindow.document
```

и плясать отсюда.

Надо отнако учесть что если родительская страница и содержимое ифреймов с разных доменов - взаимодействие между ними очень ограничего в целях безопасности.

Comment: Это то, что нужно. Спасибо. Оперативно =)

Comment: Не за что. Я подредактировал чуть-чуть чтоб точно во всех браузерах работало.